# How Java program can run python program with virtual environment?

Tags: java, python

I had several python programs and all of them had each virtual environment.

I want to run these python programs in Java program.

Now I run python program in Java like below:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)
```

but I don't know how to run with virtual enviroment. 
Can Java program run each Python program with each virtual environment?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `Runtime.exec()`, ensure that the executable being executed is the `python` interpreter located inside the virtual environment.

For example, if your virtual environment is in `/tmp/my-venv`, use the following:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/tmp/my-venv/python hello.py");
```

Or:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"/tmp/my-venv/python", "hello.py"});
```